# A side view with SWRevealViewController

Tags: objective-c

In my main view controller,I m trying to create a side view menu,and after reading every possible tutorial,I could not find any solution to this .
I have 2 other view controllers that related to storyboard view.
I am trying to load them as a side views , but i see the main navigator,button, and a black screen behind .

Here is the code i use from their example, in my main view that is loaded first .

```
 UIViewController  *side=[[sideView alloc] init];
        UIViewController  *front=[[frontView alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:front];
        UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:side];
        SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                        initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
        mainRevealController.delegate = self;
       self.viewController = mainRevealController;
    [self.view addSubview: self.viewController.view];
```